# Disable "Enable New Order Save Behavior" on newly created Dev or Trial Org to be able to install Salesforce CPQ

Tags: cpq, package-install, release, critical-update

I'm trying to install Salesforce CPQ in a new Trial or Dev org, but it fails with the following error: "Can't install the package. This package uses old Order Save Behavior and can't be part of orgs that use new Order Save Behavior.".

This issue is listed [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003wbZQAQ).

The workaround is to disable the Release Update "Enable New Order Save Behavior" as explained [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=new_order_save_behavior_setup.htm&type=5).

However, even though I can see this release update in an existing org, I can't see it in a newly created Trial Org or Dev Org.

Is this update activated by default on new Orgs ? If so, does it mean we just can't install Salesforce CPQ on any new Org ?

Comment: Reached out to our Salesforce product development team for inputs on this behavior. Will update this thread as I have more information. - Salesforce support

Comment: Update: An investigation has been filed and the R&D team is actively working on this issue. The current workaround is to sign up for a Dev Org with CPQ pre-installed and update from there. Signup at: https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/cpqtrails . Upgrade from here: https://install.steelbrick.com/

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Looks like this is also an issue on Scratch Orgs, which may quickly be an issue for dev teams using Scratch Orgs and CPQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce R&D team is actively working on this reported issue. It has been identified as a known issue.
Link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p4V0000003weE

Workaround until the issue is fixed:For Salesforce CPQ and Billing you can up for a Dev Org with CPQ pre-installed and update from there.

Signup at: developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/cpqtrails .

Upgrade from here: install.steelbrick.com

I will update this thread as I have more information. Hope this helps

Comment: I've seen the Known Issue is now scheduled for Spring '21. Have the R&D team investigate the same thing for Scratch Orgs ? If there is no way to install the CPQ package on a Scratch Org, you'll soon have problems with teams that can't work anymore if they work on DX with CPQ.

Comment: @FabienTaillon I have already notified the team about the scratch orgs. The fix should cover all these use cases ideally. Happy to discuss any followup queries you might have with our team(if any). Thanks

Comment: Do you confirm the Spring ‘21 timeframe ? If so, it’s in several months, so are we supposed to work on a project using scratch org and CPQ ? Am I missing a workaround ?

Comment: I am following up with the team on this. I will get back with more inputs.Thanks for your patience

Comment: @FabienTaillon After discussion with the team, the fix for the KI https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p4V0000003weE will be done in the patch release this week (Winter '21 Patch 12).

Comment: Great, thanks !